# display flex children behave like to have inline-block property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm getting a weird behavior using flex.

It looks like when I use `display: flex,` its children behave like to have `display: inline-block` property.

It looks like the children of a flex container expand their width to fit the content of their sub items...

[Here is the codePen](https://codepen.io/manudones/pen/rEWyBe)

How could I avoid this "inline-block behavior" using flex?

Thanks!!

Comment: adding `max-width:100%` maybe?

Comment: Adding `.container .item {
  min-width: 0;
}` will fix your _codepen_ sample and make it behave similar to `display: block`...hence I closed this as a dupe. It describes well what goes on.

Comment: A simple comparison would with a `table`, which as well won't be smaller that its _cell content_.

Comment: Thanks @LGSon, the answer in the link you shared is clear and complete